# Profiling of azul IoT JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I'm working on an `azul JVM (Profile Compact3)` on an embedded (customized) Linux. Now we want to do some profiling of the application, like deadlock and memory leak check, etc. After a while of research, I understood that profiling tools need the support of a lower-level part of JVM called `JVM Tool Interface`([JSR-163](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=163)).

My question is: how do I check if the `azul JVM` provides the `JVM Tool Interface` if I do not have access to the JVM C++ source code?

And: if it doesn't provide the `JVM Tool Interface`, is there any other way to see inner-statistics in JVM like thread stacks, heap dump, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Even though I work for Azul, the answer can be deduced from looking at the Java SE standard.  The JVM TI (JSR 163) was introduced in Java SE 5.0 (JSR 176).  JSR 176 is an umbrella JSR that includes a number of component JSRs, one of which is JSR 163.  Since the JVM TI is part of the core Java specification it must be present in order for the Azul JDK to pass the tests of the TCK, which it does.  This is the same for both our Embedded and Enterprise versions of Zulu.

The fact that you are using Compact Profile 3 has no impact because the JVM TI (as the name suggests) is part of the Virtual Machine, not the libraries.

Comment: Passing TCK does not necessary means that JVM supports all JVM TI functionality. The required JVM TI functionality is very limited. Most of interesting features are covered by the notion of [capabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#capability) that are optional.